# sql list and task by userid in a single query

Tags: mysql

is it possible to set this query in one. Or do I have to make two? 
I like to get all tasks where user is set. 
Two possiblities: User has created task or user is listed in a list of tasks.

My Query:

```
SELECT task.* FROM task, list WHERE (list.listid=task.listid AND list.userid='3') OR (task.userid='3')
```

This above query doesn't work, because of this "OR (task.userid='3')". And the list table is not mentioned in this.

These two queries work separately:

```
SELECT task.* FROM task, list WHERE (list.listid=task.listid AND list.userid='3')
SELECT task.* FROM task WHERE (task.userid='3')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a JOIN will make the queries much more logical:

```
select t.*
from task t
left join list l on l.listid = t.listid
where t.userid = '3'
```

The left join makes the task table an optional join and will return all nulls in this when there is no matching record.